# Bypassing Detection and Scraping Shopee with Selenium Wire and undetected_chromedriver not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make a shopee scraper. It is working fine with the undected_chromedriver but I want to get an API response from the network tab. So I used seleniumwire with undetected_chromedriver but the website was able to detect that it is an automation and threw a login page.

Here is my code that is not working:

```
import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as uc 
import time
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=mobile')
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Here is what I am using:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=mobile')
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code prints all the headers / API responses from the page. It uses [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) to do it. (`pip install seleniumbase`).

Copy the code to a file, and then run the file with `python` or `pytest`:

```py
from pprint import pformat
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pytest import main
    main([__file__, "--uc", "--uc-cdp", "--incognito", "-s"])

class CDPTests(BaseCase):
    def test_display_cdp_events(self):
        if not self.undetectable or not self.uc_cdp_events:
            self.get_new_driver(undetectable=True, uc_cdp_events=True)
        self.driver.add_cdp_listener("*", lambda data: print(pformat(data)))
        self.open("https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=mobile")
        self.sleep(5)
```

Since it uses `driver.add_cdp_listener`, you won't need `selenium-wire`, which doesn't play nicely with `undetected-chromedriver`. There will be a lot of output, so you may want to filter the responses for specific details.

Comment: I m not getting the response data in json. I m getting response url, status code, header but not the actual data.

Comment: I want to get the api response data, which is working fine in seleniumwire but for this website somehow it detects thats it is a bot and through login page. Right now i am using undected_chromedriver and extracting data manually.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't actually detect anything, it's just that it requires login to browse website anyhow. You either have to login (tutorial : https://www.browserstack.com/guide/login-automation-using-selenium-webdriver) or just use plain html scraping w/o selenium (getting page source as fast as possible, before it throws login banner) if it satisfies your needs.

It *might* have another solution which is to make banner invisible by changing css, but I don't think I can recommend it.

Comment: No its not like that, when we do it with undetected_chromedriver ( second code), then it will not ask any login.